# How long does it take to get a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

It's the 13th day since I applied. Four days ago, I received an email that said my application reached Sheffield and ECO would make a decision. How long does that usually take?

The tracking site doesn't say anything: it was 'green' until  reached the UKVI; after that, the status is 'red' and hasn't been updated.

My husband and children have German passports, but I don't, so I need a visa so that we can attend a party.

Comment: It takes as long as it takes. You will have been advised of the normal times while making your application. How long your specific application will take is depends on your own circumstances. Nobody here knows anything about your application that you don't know. In fact, everybody here knows less. (Unless, that is, the entry clearance officer dealing with your application happens to read this site. But they would be fired if they said anything about a specific application in public: that would be a huge breach of your privacy.)

Comment: Sheffield? What type of visa are you applying for?

Comment: Sheffield is usually for family visas isn't it?!

Comment: Also if your husband has a german passport he is a EU citizen, and the UK is still an EU country so you're husband has the right to family life which includes you're husband being allowed to go to other EU countries with you https://fullfact.org/europe/explaining-eu-deal-limiting-residence-rights/